# Copy to clipboard and cut at the same time?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard

I often copy to clipboard into other programs (changed to `<leader>y`)

is there a way to copy to the clipboard and delete once copied in one command?

For example, I want to press `<leader>y`, copy to clipboard then that line is deleted from vim.

Comment: What about just `d`? It's called "delete", but it actually cuts the contents to the clipboard

Comment: Hi @husB - it deletes with `d` but I cannot copy that content to outside programs.

Comment: You could use ``"*d`` to cut to the system clipboard or make sure the systeme clipboard is used by default by having ``:set clipboard=unnamed``

Comment: @Vinn, Ah, I see your edit now. I previously read "<leader>y" as "y", as the "<leader>" was treated as a html tag and was gobbled up. I have now edited your question accordingly, surrounding it with backticks.   What is your mapping for `<leader>y`? Perhaps we can modify it for a delete mapping.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. I didnt realise leader didn't show up in brackets @husB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have set your copy with something like:

```
nnoremap <leader>y "+y
```

You can map "cut" to:

```
nnoremap <leader>d "+d
```

PS, it might be worth it to also map visual mode too:

```
nnoremap <leader>y "+y
xnoremap <leader>y "+y
nnoremap <leader>d "+d
xnoremap <leader>d "+d
```